# jQuery .load() function doesn't return data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm having some problems with jQuery while loading an external page to get some data from mysql. The return var in the function loaded have the right data, but I am assuming it should be in the "d" variable, but it's empty.

This is the way I call the load() to the PHP script.

```
$("#msj_presupuesto").load("../Content/Scripts/ajax_circulares.php?accion=comprobar_presupuesto",{presupuesto:presupuesto}, 

    function(d){ ... }
```

Comment: What does that PHP page actually output?  When you debug this in your browser's debugging tools, what is the actual response from the server?

Comment: I think you need to use ajax `post` method here instead of `load` which is basically used to load data from the server and place the returned **HTML** into the matched element.

Comment: the PHP makes a MySQL call, and pharse some sumbers. The result will be a variable with "0" in case we have no results or a string in case we have results. I dump the variable before the return and it's working right...

Answer (score 1):

This is the whole js function:

```
$("#presupuesto_inicial").focusin(function(){
    $("#msj_presupuesto:visible").fadeOut();

}).live("change",function(){
    var presupuesto = $(this).attr("value");

    $("#msj_presupuesto").hide();

    $("#msj_presupuesto").load("../Content/Scripts/ajax_circulares.php?accion=comprobar_presupuesto",{presupuesto:presupuesto},
        function(d){
            $(this).html("");
            if(parseInt(d) == 0){
                 $(this).html("<img src=\"../Content/Images/icono_ok.png\"/> Presupuesto inicial no usado en otra circular").show();
            } else {
                $(this).html("<img src=\"../Content/Images/icono_error.png\"/> Presupuesto inicial usado en otra circular").show();
                alert("Circulares con ese presupuesto: "+d.substr(0,d.length-2));
            }
        }
    );
});
```